# How can I check the version of libusb-1.0 running on ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, versions

I have ubuntu LTS 14.04. libusb-1.0 is installed in my system. How can I check the version of this libusb-1.0?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use

```
dpkg -l libusb-1.0*
```

or

```
apt-cache policy libusb-1.0*
```